# Erro ao usar o MatTableDataBase no Angular

Tags: angular

> Type 'MatTableDataSource' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscription': closed, _parentOrParents, _subscriptions, unsubscribe, and 2 more.

Estou com esse erro no meu código, quando executo ele no navegador não da nenhum erro ele consegue trazer as pessoas que estão no banco tudo certo porém fica esse erro.

> list-users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ClienteService } from '../_services/cliente.service';
import { FuncionarioService } from '../_services/funcionario.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-users',
  templateUrl: './list-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-users.component.scss']
})
export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fs: FuncionarioService, private cs: ClienteService) { }

  // CRIA AS COLUNAS

  columnsFuncionario: string[] = ['id', 'cardID', 'user'];
  columnsClientes: string[] = ['id', 'cardID', 'name', 'cpf'];

  // RESPONSAVEL POR PEGAR OS USUARIOS E LISTAR

  funcionarioSource = this.fs.getUser().subscribe(
    response => {
      this.funcionarioSource = response;
      console.log('Sucesso ao Importar!', this.funcionarioSource);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error ao Importar!', error);
    }
  );
  clientesSouce = this.cs.getUser().subscribe(
    response => {
      this.clientesSouce = response;
      console.log('Sucesso ao Importar!', this.clientesSouce);

    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error ao Importar!', error);
    }
  );

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {

    // PARTE QUEBRADA DO CÓDIGO

    this.funcionarioSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    this.clientesSouce = new MatTableDataSource();
  }
}
```

> cliente.service.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClienteService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // USA O PROTOCOLO HTTP PARA FAZER REQUISIÇÃO NO BANCO DE DADOS

  register(userData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/clientes/', userData);
  }

  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/clientes/?format=json');
  }
}
```

> funcionario.service.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FuncionarioService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

// USA O PROTOCOLO HTTP PARA FAZER REQUISIÇÃO NO BANCO DE DADOS

  register(userData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionarios/', userData);
  }

  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/funcionarios/?format=json');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, me parece que você está atribuindo as variáveis funcionarioSource e clientesSouce dois tipos de dados: no request está atribuindo um observable, e no ngInit a um MatTableDataSource. Tenta fazer assim:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ClienteService } from '../_services/cliente.service';
import { FuncionarioService } from '../_services/funcionario.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-users',
  templateUrl: './list-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-users.component.scss']
})
export class ListUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fs: FuncionarioService, private cs: ClienteService) { }

  // CRIA AS COLUNAS

  columnsFuncionario: string[] = ['id', 'cardID', 'user'];
  columnsClientes: string[] = ['id', 'cardID', 'name', 'cpf'];

  // RESPONSAVEL POR PEGAR OS USUARIOS E LISTAR

  public funcionarioSource;
  public clientesSouce;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fs.getUser().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.funcionarioSource = response;
        console.log('Sucesso ao Importar!', this.funcionarioSource);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error ao Importar!', error);
      }
    );
    this.cs.getUser().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.clientesSouce = response;
        console.log('Sucesso ao Importar!', this.clientesSouce);

      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error ao Importar!', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!!!!!!!!!!